# why need Generic type then type reasure though we can use Object Pojo

Tags: java, generics

I have code like this:

```
public class Crate<T> {
    private T contents;

    public T emptyCrate() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void packCrate(T contents)
    {
        this.contents = contents;
    }
}
```

Now we know - in the end it will be "converted" to the following code:

```
public class Crate {
    private Object contents;

    public Object emptyCrate() {
        return contents;
    }

    public void packCrate(Object contents) 
    {
        this.contents = contents;
    }
}
```

Then why we need to create a generics if i already can create a class like `Object` Based ?

Comment: Got answer. if we create a object pojo then child method at compile time is hidden

Comment: Because if you want your `Crate` to contain `Integer`, `String`, whatever, you'd have to cast the result of `emptyCrate()` to the `Integer`, `String` or whatever - and you have to remember what type of data it contained.

Comment: Compiler will also prompt you errors, if you try to insert wrong types. And not only in runtime. Generics are programmers insurance on type safety. Many mistakes where done before java 1.5

Answer (score 2):

You see, java code is translated to bytecode. So why don't you write your programs in byte code? They get translated anyway? Or, to be precise: the JIT compiler will turn most bytecode into machine code at some point. So why do you insist on writing java source code, instead of binary machine code?!

I guess the above questions make my point clear: generics allow you to **express** intent for **human** readers. They allow you to write **better** source code; and they enable the compiler to do certain kinds of checks on your input - as nicely summarized in the other answer by Andy Turner.

That is the whole point of *any* abstraction that programming languages provide to you: they help *you* the programmer to create source code that expresses "what needs to be done" in a concise way that makes it **easier** for human readers to understand what is going on, and *why*!

Answer (score 2):

When people talk about type erasure, they normally focus upon the generic class itself. But there is another important place with generics: the call site.

For example, if you've got this code:

```
Crate<Integer> intCrate = new Crate<>();
intCrate.packCrate(0);
Integer contents = intCrate.emptyCrate();
```

Then, when it is compiled, it actually becomes:

```
Crate intCrate = new Crate();
intCrate.packCrate(0);
Integer contents = (Integer) intCrate.emptyCrate();
                 // ^ Important! This cast.
```

i.e. there are casts inserted automatically. Also, implicitly, there is a check that the parameter of `packCrate` is compatible with `Integer`, so you couldn't write:

```
intCrate.packCrate("hello");
```

Now, you can do this without generics, putting in these casts yourself, but the compiler doesn't help you to know what was put into the `Crate`. You could write something like this:

```
Crate crate = new Crate();
crate.packCrate(0);
String contents = (String) crate.emptyCrate();
```

This will fail at runtime, because the crate contains an `Integer`, not a `String`.

Generics just help you not to have to remember what you are allowed to pass to an instance, and what you will get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter what it will be turned into.

Rather the stage of compilation is important. Generics guarantee *type safety* at compile type (fixing compile-time errors is much easier than runtime ones).

It also *eliminates casts* and enables the ability to implement *generic algorithms*.

Comment: upped, but it kind of not "eliminates casts", but it eliminates the need to write them on your own.

Comment: I would say that generics *elide* casts, rather than eliminate them.

Answer (score 0):

All collections in Java are Generics. It's the best example of using Generics. For example you create class List. Which types of objects will it hold? When you create `List` class, you don't know about which types it will hold, so you use Generics. And when you use `List`class, you say, that you want to put `Integers`(`new List<Integer`).

Answer (score 0):

Template parameters in generics are used for compile time safety. Compiler will choke if you write for example:

```
Crate<Integer> cr;
Object o;

cr.packCrate(o);  // compilation error here
```

It can also declare that any class used as parameter will implement some methods:

```
Interface I {
    void myMethod();
}

class Crate<T extends I> {
    private T contents;
    ...
    public void applyMethod() {
        contents.myMethod();      // T shall implement myMethod
    }
}
```

In fact everything could be done by explicit casting, but you will get only run time errors while generics allow compile time detection of errors.